# Fatal error : no such path "file path" exist in commit id

Tags: git

I was trying to run a .sh file which will fetch author details per commit for all files for an application. It was working fine for sample files but when i am trying to run the same shell script for few combination of files and commit id i am getting fatal error saying the path doesnt exist in particular commit id. But in real the same commit id is present for that file.

Please explain the possible reason for the issue and suggest some solution so that i can overcome the issue . Below is the code i am using

```
#!/bin/bash
# get the list of files present in the current directory
files=`git ls-files "*.java"`
# removing whitespace
fn=( $files )
# using for loop to iterate through each file
for ((j=0; j <${#fn[@]}; j++))
do
    # To get the file name - as the fn returns the sub-directory path
    filename=$(basename ${fn[$j]})
# split the Set of SHA values 
IFS=';' 
arr=($SHA)
# To iterate through each commit of the file
    for ((i=0; i <${#arr[@]}; i++))
    do
    echo *fileName*
    echo $filename
    echo *EndfileName*
    # To remove new line from the SHA id 
    commitId1=$(echo ${arr[$i]}|tr -d '\n')
    owner=`git blame --line-porcelain ${fn[$j]} $commitId1 | grep "^author " | sort | uniq -c`
    done
done
```

I am new to shell script and git . So forgive me if the code is not good

Comment: i was able to run for around 1000 other files for the same application . And even for other commit id of the files in which i faced issue.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the authors, simply execute

```
git log --format='%aN'
```

The following will also print `commit hash`:

```
git log --format='%aN %H'
```

`git log` supports many more formats : Refer [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats)

Comment: ok.... but any idea why the above error shown for few combination of files and commit id ...... Is it because of some reason